Did David have 33 or 37 mighty warriors?
David's special forces are recorded in 2 Samuel 23:8-38 and 1 Chronicles 11:10–47.
The text divides them into "the Three", of which there are three, and "the Thirty", of which there are more than thirty.
The text explicitly states that there are 37 individuals in all, but it is unclear whether this refers to The Thirty, which may or may not contain The Three, or the combined total of both groups.
There seems to be Thirty and Three, 33.
But were there officially 33 men or 37 men?

And does this have a connection with the 33 days of impurity after giving birth to a male?
